# How to have multiple plist files for a target which combine at run time

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, plist

In my Swift iOS project, I have multiple targets. These targets share most of the properties in info.plist but only a couple of properties have different values for each target.

I want to have once central primary info.plist which applies to all app targets AND then a secondary infoTarget1.plist which applies to Target1 only and a inforTarget2.plist which applies on Target2 only and so on.

In the end the properties of both info.plist and infoTargetX.plist should combine.

How can this be accomplished?

Comment: You would need to use a build time script to create the single info.plist file for the target